# How to set Azure API Backend to Azure resource in XML Policy file?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-api-management

In Azure APIM portal, you can set backend as Azure resource, for example, Logic App, but how can we do it programatically using XML Policy file?

cheers,

[Backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6Tls.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the  [set-backend-service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBackendService) policy to redirect an incoming request to a different backend than the one specified in the API settings for that operation. This policy changes the backend service base URL of the incoming request to the one specified in the policy.

Comment: thank you! It should be the way to sort the problem, however, I'm after some cmd-let can directly specify the Logic App or other services in the Policy file. Looks like it's not available yet.

Comment: Try to externalize parameters using "Named Parameters" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-properties) and modify them using Rest API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/property)..

Comment: thank you! this Named value really help and I see it in the APIM generated policy file and now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the "Web service URL" setting but this value kept being overridden each time I imported a new swagger.json file.

Solved it by using a policy:

```
   <policies>
        <inbound>
            <base />
            <set-backend-service base-url="https://api-mysite.azurewebsites.net" />
        </inbound>
        <backend>
            <base />
        </backend>
        <outbound>
            <base />
        </outbound>
        <on-error>
            <base />
        </on-error>
    </policies>
```

many thanks to @MKaz for leading me in the right direction :)